# PHP variable with a value of string is not equal in PHP variable with a value of html id from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, string, variables

This is my example code

```
<script>
    var item = "yooow";
    jQuery("#view").html(item);
</script>

<?php  $str_html = '<p id="view"></p>';

     echo $str_html; //it will output "yooow" 
?>
```

but...

when i'm trying to compare this into another php variable

```
<?php $str_php ="yooow";

    if($str_html == $str_php)
    {
         echo "true";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "false"; 
    }
?>
```

but it returns to false

how can they be an equal?

Comment: You're setting `$str_html` to  `'<p id="view"></p>'`, not `'yooow'`

Comment: `$str_html` is `<p id="view"></p>` and `$str_php` is `yooow` in your case.

Comment: PHP parses the script first. After the HTML (and Javascript_) is loaded in the browser, Jquery works

Comment: is there a chance to make them equal since their output is the same?

Comment: how can they be equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better, you give the item value in cookie/session. And, compare the cookie value with $str_php.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var item = "<?php  echo $_SESSION['html']="yooow"; ?>";
    $("#view").html(item);
});
</script>
<?php  
    $str_html = '<p id="view"></p>';
    $strHtml=$_SESSION['html'];
    $str_php ="yooow";
    if($strHtml == $str_php)
    {
         echo "true";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "false"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: i have another question. how can i pass a string variable from php to javascript then javascript to php ?

Comment: @Aislinn I believe it's impossible to convert javascript to PHP. Since PHP is server side and JavaScript is client side.

Comment: @Déjàvu how about ajax?

Answer (score 2):

PHP is run serverside which means it's not aware of any changes you make in the DOM using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var item = "yooow";
```

**Value set only in clinet side, PHP don't know about changes here**

```
jQuery("#view").html(item);   
</script>

<?php  $str_html = '<p id="view"></p>';
```

**WRONG, it will output "<p id="view"></p>"**
     echo $str_html; //it will output "yooow" ?>

```
<?php $str_php ="yooow";
```

**Comparing "<p id="view"></p>" and "yoow" and that is not equal!**

```
 if($str_html == $str_php)
```

Comment: @Aislinn no, you are setting `#view` innerHtml to "yoow". Remove JS and will see

Comment: i must not remove the JS.